# Hey everyone! I want to keep my validation simple and still use a different conditions to every input in my function

Tags: reactjs, validation, jsx

I made some form validation in react, Can i use a few global variables from my state in one function for my form validation? Whats the way to keep it simple and still give a different conditions to every input? something wrong and I'd like to some help, I would like to not include the regexp pattern for the email or anything..
Thanks Everyone!

Registration.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Registration extends Component {

    state={
        userName:'',
        password:'',
        email:'',
        age:'',
        backgroundColorInput:'white'
    }
    
    validLoginDetails=(item)=> {
    
    locationOfS = email.indexOf('@');
    
    this.setState({userName:item.target.value});
    
    if(item.target.value.length>5 && item.target.value.length<9){
        this.setState({backgroundColorInput:'green'})
    }

    this.setState({password:item.target.value});

    if(item.target.value.length<7){
        this.setState({backgroundColorInput:'red'})
    }

    
    this.setState({email:item.target.value});

    if (item.target.value.locationOfS.indexOf(4) != -1) {
        this.setState({backgroundColorInput:'green'} )
      }

    else{
    
        this.setState({backgroundColorInput:'red'})
    
    }
    
   
        
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                
        <input placeholder='Enter your name' onChange={this.validLoginDetails} style={{backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColorInput}} /><br/>
        <input type='password' placeholder='Enter your a password' onChange={this.validLoginDetails} style={{backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColorInput}} /><br/>
        <input placeholder='Enter your Age' onChange={this.validLoginDetails} style={{backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColorInput}} /><br/>
        <input type="email" placeholder='Enter your Email' onChange={this.validLoginDetails} style={{backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColorInput}} /><br/>
        <button onClick={this.func}>submit</button>


                
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Registration from './components/Registration.js';
import Main from './components/Main.js';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     


     <Registration/>
     <Main/>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of my recent problems and solutions that I hope will help you.

Recently I want to create a signup page with react. I need a library help me manage the form state and validate the form values. Then I choose the famous 'formik' + 'Yup'. But after some try, I found that it was not up to the job.

formik validate every fields when any fields value change or blur. For simple validation, it is not a big problem. But I need to check the usability of user name and email through network which may cost many time. And when checking, A spin is presented to the user. So the validation can't be triggered by change event. On the other hand, if the user name has been checked and not change, it should not be checked again. Becuase the user will not want to see a spin when he doesn't change the user name field. For almost all the form library, validation will be triggered before submit. but for those fields  which has been validated and not changed yet, the validation should not be triggered. Formik is difficult to achieve the above requirements

At last I developed my own [library](https://github.com/vipcxj/powerful-form-hook). It support validate each field with separate triggers.
by and large there are three trigger: change, blur and submit.

For change, when the field value changed, the validation happen.
For blur, the situation will be a bit complicated. When the blur happen, if the field already has an error and the field has not changed from last validation, it should not be validated again. If the field has not an error, and the field value has not changed from last validation, it should not be validated again. If the field has not an error, but the field has been changed from last validation, it should be validated now.
For submit, similar to the 'blur' event, when submit happen, if the field already has an error and the field value has not been changed from last validation, no need to validate again, and terminate submission. If the field has not error and the field value has not been changed from the last validation, the field is considered to have been validated and does not need to be re-validated. If the field has not error and the field value has been changed from the last validation, a validation task should be started again.

There is a working [demo](http://localhost:6006/?path=/story/useform--demo)

This is the code example

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createValidator, useForm, OnSubmitFunction, REG_SPECIAL, string, sameWithWhenExists } from 'powerful-form-hook';


export const Demo = () => {
  const initialValues = React.useMemo(() => ({
    userName: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    conformedPassword: '',
    age: '',
  }), []);
  const validate = React.useMemo(() => createValidator<typeof initialValues>({
    userName: (value) => {
      if (!value) throw 'User name is required.'
      if (value.length > 5 && value.length < 9) throw 'The length of user name should longer than 5 and shortter than 9.'
    },
    password: [
      string()
        .required('Password is required.')
        .composedOf('Password must be composed of upper and lower case letters, Numbers and special keyboard symbols', /[a-z]+/i, /\d+/, REG_SPECIAL)
        .matchSomeOf('The password must contain uppercase letters or special keyboard symbols', /[A-Z]+/, REG_SPECIAL)
        .min(6, 'Password length must be greater than or equal to 6')
        .max(24, 'Password length must be less than or equal to 24'),
      // the validate task will trigger by blur of itself and conformedPassword field.
      {
        triggers: {
          trigger: 'blur',
          fields: ['conformedPassword'],
        },
        validate: sameWithWhenExists('conformedPassword', 'Enter the same password twice'),
      },
    ],
    conformedPassword: [
      string('Password should be a string.'),
      // the validate task will trigger by blur of itself and password field.
      {
        triggers: {
          trigger: 'blur',
          fields: ['password'],
        },
        validate: sameWithWhenExists('password', 'Enter the same password twice'),
      },
    ],
    age: string().matchSomeOf(/\d+/)
    // same as userName.
    email: [
      string().required('Email is required.').trimmed('Email can not start or end with space.'),
    ],
  }), []);
  // Only when validate successful, the form submit. And if some validate task is running in the background or the form is submitting, the form will not be sumbited.
  const onSubmit: OnSubmitFunction<typeof initialValues> = React.useCallback(async (values: typeof initialValues) => {
    alert('submit successful');
  }, []);
  // handleChanges accept both event and value. For default, handleChanges will extract the value from event.target.value. For component like CheckBox which accept checked, use handleChanges[field].checked.
  const { errors, values, handleChanges, handleBlurs, handleSubmit, submitting, validating } = useForm({
    initialValues,
    validate,
    onSubmit,
  });
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
        <div>
            <input placeholder='Enter your name' onChange={handleChanges.userName} onBlur={handleBlurs.userName} />
            { errors.userName.error ? errors.userName.message : null }
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type='password' placeholder='Enter your a password' onChange={handleChanges.password} onBlur={handleBlurs.password} />
            { errors.password.error ? errors.password.message : null }
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type='password' placeholder='Conform your a password' onChange={handleChanges.conformedPassword} onBlur={handleBlurs.conformedPassword} />
            { errors.conformedPassword.error ? errors.conformedPassword.message : null }
        </div>
        <div>
            <input placeholder='Enter your Age' onChange={handleChanges.age} onBlur={handleBlurs.age} />
            { errors.age.error ? errors.age.message : null }
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="email" placeholder='Enter your Email' onChange={handleChanges.email} onBlur={handleBlurs.email} />
            { errors.email.error ? errors.email.message : null }
        </div>
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
         { submitting ? 'Submitting...' : validating ? 'Validating...' : null }
    </form>
  )
}
```